# Is it possible to execute javascript code in a v-for loop without displaying its output?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to run a code that increments a variable so that I can change the argument given to the component that is being rendered by the list.

```
 <li v-for="card in cards" :key="card">
      <app-profile :id="cards[i]"></app-profile>
      <p>{{ i++ }}</p>
 </li>
```

The prop that is being passed is an element from an array called cards, but I want to access the subsequent element of cards every time the loop occurs, passing a the next element in the cards array to the app-profile component as a prop.

However, I don't want this incrementation to be rendered like it would be if I ran

```
{{ i++ }}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: cards is an array filled with elements that I want to iterate through, and i is a number variable that I want to increment every time v-for loops

Comment: I don't think we're on the same page here. The code is functional but it renders "i" on screen as I have typed {{ i++ }}. I don't need to debug the code, but rather not render "i".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using post-increment operator `i++` like:

```
<li v-for="card in cards" :key="card">
  <app-profile :id="cards[i++]"></app-profile>
</li>
```